# Odoo 13 How to expand attachments by default?

Tags: view, odoo, attachment, odoo-13

Is it possible to set up View form to expand attachments by default?
When you open record where attachments are, you need click to clip button to see preview of attachments. How can I setup it to be open by default?

[image: Closed attachments]

[image: Open attachments]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script in the form view to automatically click the attachment button after the form has loaded. Try to add the following code in the form tag:

```
<script>$("button.o_chatter_button_attachment").click();</script>
```

When there are no attachments, the value of the button count (span) is `0` with blank spaces. You can use that value to show the attachments preview when there are attachments.

```
<script>
    if ($(".o_chatter_attachment_button_count").text().trim() != '0') {
        $("button.o_chatter_button_attachment").click();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: where should I put this script in my project? I put it on may form view in record but I didn't work, can you tell me about that?

Comment: Add the script inside the form tag, the button classes has changed in Odoo 14. I added an answer to [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68117590/how-to-override-existed-component-in-owl-odoo-14-trigger-click-function-everyt).