# How to override existed component in owl Odoo 14 / trigger click function everytime go to view in Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, components, odoo, odoo-14

When we open mail.chatter view, we have a "paperclip" icon, when we click on it then  will be visible, we can see all attachment file, this is normal flow. But I want to change that `<AttachmentBox>`'s always opened when we get into chatter view. (no need to click to "paperclip" icon to open)
After finding stuffs, I found that have 2 two ways to do that, but I can not how to implement it.

Option 1: How to trigger click function everytime when we go to view

```
_onClickAttachments(ev) {
    this.chatter.update({
    isAttachmentBoxVisible: !this.chatter.isAttachmentBoxVisible,
    });
}
```

Option 2: How can I override constructor of `<Chatter/>` component( owl) to set `chatter.isAttachmentBoxVisible = true`, so when this component's created, it's always true.

How to implement that function?Thank you guy so much

Answer (score 1):

You can display the attachments box by default using the `open_attachments` option on the [message_ids](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/mail/static/src/js/basic_view.js#L20-L23) field.

***Example:***

```
<field name="message_ids" options="{'open_attachments': True}"/>
```